# Renaming of multiple files via batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, dos, batch-rename

I have this part of batch script which is doing following:

***-Under every sub-folder it renames files: 'jpg,gif,png' to 'Poster 1', 'Poster 2', 'Poster 3' and so on... (no change on extension)***

```
set i=0
for %%b in (*.jpg *.gif *.png) do (
  set /A i+=1
   ren "%%b" "Poster !i!%%~Xb"
  echo File "%%b" renamed to "Poster !i!%%~Xb"
)
```

rem PATCH to fix a bug in previous FOR command (**PLEASE IGNORE:** *there isa bug in prev. FOR command, which renames one file twice, **if there are just two image files** in a folder*) :

```
if !i! neq 0 if not exist "Poster 1.*" (
  ren "Poster !i!.*" "Poster 1.*"
  echo ...and renamed back to "Poster 1"
)
```

**!!!!! What I need is following: !!!!!**
-I need to add a requirement **if there is just a one file** in the folder to rename it to "**Poster**", as without it this script renames it to 'Poster 1'
Thank you!

Comment: When renaming files in a folder it is better to parse the output of the `DIR` command with a `FOR /F` instead of using a basic `FOR` command to iterate the files.  The `FOR` command is working on one file at a time.  It is not aware of all of the files at time of execution.  Just if you rename A.txt to Z.txt it will try and rename Z.txt as well with a basic `FOR` command.

Comment: The `FOR /F` command does not start executing until the entire `DIR` command has completed.  So any files you rename will not be present within the execution of the `FOR /F command because the IN clause has already completed.

Answer (score 1):

Just a logical solution, After the do loop , you can check the value of 'i' again and if it is 1 then you can perform the rename operation once again[Rename Poster1 to Poster]. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

After the patch `if` command:

```
if !i! equ 1 ren "Poster 1.*" "Poster.*"
```

**EDIT**:

If you insert previous line after the patch `if` command (as I said), the final code is this:

```
set i=0
for %%b in (*.jpg *.gif *.png) do (
   set /A i+=1
   ren "%%b" "Poster !i!%%~Xb"
   echo File "%%b" renamed to "Poster !i!%%~Xb"
)
rem PATCH to fix a bug in previous FOR command:
if !i! neq 0 if not exist "Poster 1.*" (
   ren "Poster !i!.*" "Poster 1.*"
   echo ...and renamed back to "Poster 1"
)
REM NEW COMMAND TO RENAME THE UNIQUE FILE TO "Poster":
if !i! equ 1 ren "Poster 1.*" "Poster.*"
```

Antonio

Comment: It does not work, the batch can not be run if I replace the if command or add a new one at the bottom. This request should be on top. So it should work if there are more than 3 files (Poster 1, Poster 2, Poster 3...), more than 1 file (Poster 1, Poster 2) and only 1 file (Poster). Thanks

Comment: I don't said "replace the if command" nor "at the bottom", I said "after the patch if command". The only way to know if there is just one file (to rename it without the " 1") is _after_ counting how many files are. See my edit...

Comment: Thank you, I tried that, but with no luck, it starts with 1. Poster 1. And also there is no output to identify the problem :(

Comment: Perhaps if you show us what the original file is, what you get and what you expect, we could help you in a better way. Right now, I have no idea of what your problem is... _Please_, use an EDIT in your question to explain the problem in a concise, but complete way, NOT the limited space and formatting of these comments. As I said you before, phrases like "does not work", "with no luck", "it start with 1. Poster 1" (and so?) are just chitchat that have no useful information. If _you know_ what the problem is, then _tell us_ please!